# Which defensive check is preferable when querying data using the Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Which of the following defensive checks is preferable when querying data using the Entity Framework?

**1. The `null` check:**

```
user = users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email.Equals(email));

if(user == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Some critical error!");
}

OperationsOnUser(user);
```

**2. LINQ's `Any()`:**

```
if(users.Any(u => u.Email.Equals(email)))
{
    user = users.Single(u => u.Email.Equals(email));
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Some critical error!");
}

OperationsOnUser(user);
```

Personally I use the second option because it feels cleaner to me, but am I not performing two database calls instead of one?  I'm unsure about the inner mechanics of Entity Framework.

Comment: If there *has* to be a user, then maybe just go with `users.Single(u => ...)` and let the `InvalidOperationException` pop up if there's more than one element in a sequence?

Comment: With the second one, what happens if the `user` record gets deleted between the two database calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I will quote Jon Skeet:](http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/19-Join.html)

> I always advise
>   anyone implementing a LINQ-like operator to only iterate over any
>   input sequence once. There are sequences which are impossible to
>   iterate over multiple times, or which may give different results each
>   time. That's bad news.

Keep the habits to iterate only one time.

For your example, yes, you are accessing twice the database, and that's not a good idea.
In fact, your second option feel to me a lot lot messier than the first option. You need to recalibrate your messy-detector! :)

Comment: Thanks for the reference - all hail The Skeet.  The reason why it is messy to me is because of the use of `null`.  `null` has no concrete semantic meaning so I do try to avoid it whenever possible, but I need to be careful here :)

Comment: @davenewza not sure about your anti-`null` position, but if you like, you could `Where` and `ToList` and then check the count of the resulting list; presumably if this list has `0` members that is sufficiently meaningful?

Answer (score 1):

AakashM's comment is correct.  But to expand on that, (1) is better because you're doing a single operation on the database whilst in the second example you're doing it twice.  Once to see it is there, and once to use it.  I think the answer is self-evident from my perspective.